# How to rescale label on x axis in log2(n+1) format?

Tags: r, plot, scale

I want to format my x-axis in `log2(n+1)` format so the x-axis labels correspond to 1, 2, 4, 16 and so on.

Input:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 11, 15)
y <- c(1.1, 1.2, .4, 2.1, 1.5)

plot(log2(x + 1), y, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=(labels=as.character(formatC(x))), cex.axis=0.9)
```

But plot I get still has the original x-axis values.

[image]

How can I make my x-axis powers of 2 (1, 2, 4, 16, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,11,15) 
y<-c(1.1,1.2,.4,2.1,1.5)
lab<-c(1,2,4,16)
plot(log2(x+1),y,xaxt="n",xlab="x")
axis(1,at=log2(lab+1),labels=lab)
```

It might also be useful to calculate equally spaced labels:

```
lab<-round(2^seq(min(log2(x+1)),max(log2(x+1)),length.out=4)-1)
```

Comment: i need c(1,2,4,8,16,32) equally spaced. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: For `log2(x+1)` the sequence 1,3,7,15,31 would be equally spaced. Yours would be for `log2(x)`.

Comment: x<-c(15.918,  8.822,  0.619,  0.060,  0.479,  2.913,  2.456,  0.927,  1.121  0.255, 0.000,  0.549,  0.095)                                                                    y<-c(19,  7,  0,  0,  1,  3 , 2,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0)
                                                                    if i use ur series                                                   lab<-round(2^seq(min(log2(x+1)),max(log2(x+1)),length.out=6)-1)
                                                                 i get 0  1  2  4  9 16  but i need to add 1,3,7,15,31 (as u suggested) equally spaced. How can i do it?

Comment: You can always define the labels explicitly (as I have shown above).